# How can i get the inner value of a node in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML like:

```
<Employee>
<Name> XXXX </Name>
<Address> YYYY </Addeess>
<Country> ZZZZ </Country>
</Employee>
```

How can i get the inner value of Country? Here Country is dynamically generated(based on user input).

It may be present or not. If present i need to fetch the inner value using c#.

Comment: Where are you stuck in code with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var countryElement = XElement.Parse(xml).Element("Country");
 string result = (countryElement != null) ? countryElement.Value : string.Empty;
```

Comment: I tried like                                                 `XmlDocument xdoc= new XmlDocument(); xdoc.LoadXml(xmlpath);     var countryElement = XElement.Parse(xdoc).Element("Country"); string result = (countryElement != null) ? countryElement.Value : string.Empty;`                                                      It does not allow Parse(xdoc) says invalid arguments.

Comment: @user1658567: If you load from file, use Load, not Parse

Answer (score 3):

This may help you :

```
XmlDocument ob = new XmlDocument();
ob.Load("yourxmlfile.xml");
XmlNodeList obj_country = ob.GetElementsByTagName("Country");
  if(obj_country!= null)
     {
        string innertext_country_node = obj_country[0].InnerText;
     }
```